# Grails enum as domain property intermittently saving as ordinal value in database

Tags: grails, enums

Grails 2.3.7, Java 1.7, tomcat

For no apparent reason(that I can see) the reviewResults property of the Review domain sometimes saves as the ordinal value of the enum.

The database schema says that the column is a varchar type.

Sometimes NA is saved as NA, however, sometimes it is saved as 0.

This is the same with passed, except passed is saved as 1 sometimes.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
abstract class Work {
    // Nothing defined in here related 
    // to the review domain enum.
}
```

The Domain class in question.

```
class Review extends Work {
    Results reviewResults
    String notes

    enum Results {
        NA,
        Passed,
        Error
    }

    static constraints = {
        reviewResults(nullable: true, enumType: 'string')
    }

    // Is this redundant if it is already declared in the constraints?
    static mapping = {
        reviewResults enumType: 'string'
    }
}
```

The Domains related controller.

```
// Reviews created with Quartz job, results property is not set.
class ReviewController {
    def reviewService

    def show(Long id) {
        def reviewInstance = Review.get(id)

        def reviewResultsOptions = []
        reviewResultsOptions.addAll(com.mycompany.app.Review.Results.values())

        [reviewInstance: reviewInstance, reviewResultsOptions: reviewResultsOptions]
    }

    def closeWork(Long id, String reviewResults, String notes) {
        def review = Review.get(id)

        review.reviewResults = Review.Results.valueOf(reviewResults)

        def result = reviewService.closeReview(review, notes)
    }
}
```

The service for the controller/domain.

```
class ReviewService {
    def workService

    Review closeReview(Review work, String notes) {
        work.notes = notes
        workService.closeWork(work)

        return work.errors.allErrors.empty ? work : null
    }
}
```

The service where the Review object is finally saved.

```
class WorkService {
    Tracking closeWork(Work workInstance) {
        def tracked = new Tracking()

        workInstance.setStatus(status)
        workIntance.setClosed(new Date())

        WorkInstance.save(flush: true)

        // Set some tracking properties and save and return the tracking object.
    }
}
```